# Erro exceptions.OptimisticLockException ao tentar realizar UPDATE com JPA

Tags: jpa, persistência

Estou tendo problema quando tento realizar um update com JPA 
com a instrução:

```
ObjetoDE = thisObjetoBF.update(ObjetoDE);
```

ERROR:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-5010] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.2.v20130514-5956486):
    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.OptimisticLockException
    Exception Description: 
        The object [ObjetoDE{ChaveUidK=355}] 
        cannot be merged because it has changed or been deleted since it was last read. 
    Class> com.xxx.yyyy.domain.admin.entity.TabelaDE
```

Comentei todos os campos passando para o Update somente a chave do registro e mesmo assim persiste o erro, Teriam alguma idéia ?

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri que isso ocorre devido a versão que fica desatualiza e consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
ObjetoDE old = this.repository.findByID(de.getCampoChave());
        de.setUpdateS(old.getUpdateS());
```

O link https://www.mkyong.com/jpa/jpa-optimistic-lock-exception-in-java-development/ explica os detalhes desse processo.